# How to differentiate the same data by different markers and keep the color of markers and lines the same by PlotMarkers?

Tags: plotting, color, data, visualization

```
xrange = {-1, 1};
xdata = {{1, 0., 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1}};
ListLinePlot[Append[#\[Transpose], Total[#, {2}]] &[xdata], DataRange -> 
MinMax[xrange],PlotMarkers -> {{"\!\(\*TemplateBox[{\nCell[\n\
TextData[\"\\\\[FivePointedStar]\"]], \
\"paclet:ref/character/FivePointedStar\"},\n\"RefLink\",\n\
BaseStyle->{\"InlineCharacterName\"}]\)", 
Scaled[0.03]}, {"\!\(\*TemplateBox[{\nCell[\n\
TextData[\"\\\\[EmptyUpTriangle]\"]], \
\"paclet:ref/character/EmptyUpTriangle\"},\n\"RefLink\",\n\
BaseStyle->{\"InlineCharacterName\"}]\)", 
Scaled[0.03]}, {"\!\(\*TemplateBox[{\nCell[\n\
TextData[\"\\\\[EmptyCircle]\"]], \
\"paclet:ref/character/EmptyCircle\"},\n\"RefLink\",\n\
BaseStyle->{\"InlineCharacterName\"}]\)", 
Scaled[0.03]}, {"\!\(\*TemplateBox[{\nCell[\n\
TextData[\"\\\\[EmptySquare]\"]], \
\"paclet:ref/character/EmptySquare\"},\n\"RefLink\",\n\
BaseStyle->{\"InlineCharacterName\"}]\)", Scaled[0.03]}}, 
PlotLegends -> {"1", "2", "3", "4"}, Frame -> True, GridLines -> None]
ListLinePlot[Append[#\[Transpose], Total[#, {2}]] &[xdata], 
DataRange -> MinMax[xrange], 
PlotMarkers -> {{Automatic, Scaled[0.02]}, {Automatic, 
Scaled[0.03]}, {Automatic, Scaled[0.03]}, {Automatic, 
Scaled[0.03]}}, PlotLegends -> {"1", "2", "3", "4"}, 
Frame -> True, GridLines -> None]
```

[image: horizontal lines at 0.0, 1.0, and 2.0; but you can't see that there are actually five lines]

The data of "1" and "3" in the picture are the same, I need to differentiate them, so I use specific markers like this, but the color of the lines that share the markers are different from the markers. I want to make them the same. So I use "Automatic", the color of the lines that share the markers are the same with the markers, but the a new problem is that now the data "1" are covered by "3".

[image: still can't see that there are actually five graphs]
So how to solve it?

---

**Update**

After studying the grammar of PlotMarkers and comparing the difference between my code that express markers and the answer's, I find the problem of my previous code is that I use some unnecessary code. For example, mine is

```
"\!\(\*TemplateBox[{\nCell[\n\TextData[\"\\\\[FivePointedStar]\"]],  \\"paclet:ref/character/FivePointedStar\"},\n\"RefLink\",\n\ BaseStyle-> 
{\"InlineCharacterName\"}]\)"
```

And the answer's is

```
 "\[FivePointedStar]"
```

And mine is markers copy from the documentation directly.
If I write it by myself like

```
"\[FivePointedStar]"
```

Then I can control it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can play with the size of each marker this way `{MarkerName,Size}`

```
xrange = {-1, 1};
xdata = {{1, 0., 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1}};
ListLinePlot[Append[Transpose[#], Total[#, {2}]] &[xdata], 
 DataRange -> MinMax[xrange], 
 PlotMarkers -> {{"\[FivePointedStar]", 25}, {"\[FilledUpTriangle]", 
    20}, {"\[FilledCircle]", 10}, {"\[FilledSquare]", 20}}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"1", "2", "3", "4"}, Frame -> True, 
 GridLines -> None, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I am inspired by your answer,and I change the "FivePointedStar" to "Circle[]//Graphics" and adjust the size,the effect is better to differantiate the data.Thank you again